# Reminders app bottom week uiscrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to figure how to mimic this control. i tried using IAInfintegridview, but it was too complicated to customize it.

What im trying to achieve is exactly the same control with selectable weekdays.

Sorry for the english

**Edit:**
I'll try be more specific.
I'm trying to create an horizontal uiscrollview which consist of 7 uiviews. one for each day of the week. this scroll will be infinite to both sides so you can scroll through the whole calander.

every uiview in the uiscrollview will be touchable and will send a message to its delegate that it has been pressed.

Comment: Your question should be much more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your infinite uiscrollview, implement uiscrollviewdelegate and try this :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int currentPage = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2)/pageWidth) + 1;
    if (currentPage==0) {
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [dayOfWeek count],0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    } else if (currentPage==([myCovers count]+1)) {
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width,0,scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
    }
    [self adjustDataInScrollviewHere];
}
```